# How does Prometheus labeling syntax works?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

I'm new to Prometheus and I have a very basic question.

What is the syntax to add a label to my Metrics?
I tried the following:

```
1. Gauge.build().name(name).labelNames("label"="someLabel").help(helpMsg).register(registry);
2. Gauge.build().name(name).labelNames(label=someLabel).help(helpMsg).register(registry);
4. Gauge.build().name(name).labelNames("someLabel").help(helpMsg).register(registry);
```

The docs say String value, which I tried...

Someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question lacks helpful detail to aid answering.

I assume you're using the Java SDK.

Here's the link to the documentation:

https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#labels

It appears you should use:

```java
g = Gauge.build()
  .name(name)
  .labelNames("someLabel")
  .help(helpMsg)
  .register(registry);
```

And then, when you update your gauge (`g`), you need to specify the label(s) value(s):

```java
g
  .labels("someLabelValue")
  .set(...);
```

Comment: I tried that. Although I see my metric in the Prometheus metrics list, I don't see the label appears

Comment: Updated my answer.... when you e.g. `Set` the Gauge's value, you need to set the label value(s) too.

Comment: I see... Thank you DazWilkin!